# Safari opens pdf in browser window, but doesn't auto rotate and there is no control bar

Tags: safari, pdf, web-browser

I just recently switched to a macbook pro with mountain lion from macbook with leopard. I had no problems with safari opening pdfs before, but now, what it does is that it opens the pdf, but it remains vertical (an otherwise landscape document) and there isn't even a control bar to zoom, or rotate it.
Does anyone have a suggestion?
Thx

Comment: If you can, please give a URL for a PDF where the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a secure, password protected website for my work schedule, but I'll try to find something that does the same

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using OS X Preview in Safari.

*Note: If you don't have Acrobat or Reader, or haven't installed the PDFViewer plug-in, then Safari shows PDF files using the Mac OS X native PDF support.*

#### Solution 1

Get Adobe Reader XI (11.0.02) installed, inclusive the browser plugin. Now Safari will open the .PDF files in Adobe Reader, and you can easily modify what you see (e.g. rotate the documents).

#### Solution 2

Try right click (or two fingers click on my MacBook Air) on the PDF document, that should open a window to rotate the document.